# Why are images not working after migrating Rails 7 app from Heroku to Railway? (S3 images not showing, new image upload crashes app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 app with Postgresql database and AWS S3 image storage. It's currently deployed on Heroku and I want to migrate to Railway (https://railway.app/).

I have successfully deployed the app and migrated the database to Railway, and everything is working fine EXCEPT images. The ones already uploaded to S3 aren't showing up, and when I try to add a new image, the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed)
```

I have tried reinstalling ImageMagick but it doesn't do anything. Everything is still working fine on the Heroku deployment.

In addition, every time I deploy on Railway, it says I don't have Ruby 3.2.1 installed, so it reinstalls it each time and deployment takes about 6 minutes (instead of 30 seconds on Heroku). I get this warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /usr/local/rvm/gems/3.1.2/bin is not available.
```

Could they be related somehow?
Could there be something to do with AWS S3 that makes it so the images don't show up?

Is there something I need to do to install ImageMagick and Ruby 3.2.1 directly into Railway? Why does it not recognize them?

**Update:**

I added the following to my variables, and switched to the Heroku buildpack (in Railway) per [this article](https://github.com/railwayapp/nixpacks/issues/409) and [this discord thread](https://discord.com/channels/713503345364697088/1026991218074325012/1026999965299507200).

```
NIXPACKS_PKGS=imagemagick
NIXPACKS_APT_PKGS=libimagemagick-dev
```

Now I no longer get the Ruby 3.2.1 path warning. I am able to add an image BUT it seems like it's only in local storage. When I refresh the app crashes again, with an empty error message in the logs:

```
I, [2022-11-02T06:31:25.034636 #120]  INFO -- : [8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7025ms (ActiveRecord: 94.6ms | Allocations: 106325)
F, [2022-11-02T06:31:25.036160 #120] FATAL -- : [8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35] ActionView::Template::Error (`convert /tmp/ActiveStorage-118-20221102-120-zx3huu.jpg[0] -auto-orient -resize 150x150> /tmp/image_processing20221102-120-yfhkye.jpg` failed with error:
):
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     54:         <% if review.images.exists? %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     55:           <% review.images.each do |image| %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     56:             <% if review.images.attached? && image.content_type.in?(%w[image/gif image/jpeg image/png]) %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     57:               <%= link_to image_tag(review.image_as_thumbnail(image)), image, class: "img-thumbnail border-0 px-0", target: :_blank %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     58:             <% end %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     59:           <% end %>
[8a1f130e-6718-4a29-9f9f-d3a27f200e35]     60:         <% end %>
```

**2nd Update**

It seems like it's happening only for images I already uploaded. Is it possible that Heroku adds something to images uploaded to ensure they're unique, that I would have to do in the code instead when using Railway?

Comment: Heroku provides ImageMagick in its stock images. 
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages and ActiveStorage uses Vips or ImageMagick to extract metadata for attachments https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#requirements

Also make sure ruby version is specified correctly. 
 https://nixpacks.com/docs/providers/ruby

Comment: Does this mean that railway simply doesn't support imagemagick, or is there some way I can install it? Regarding the ruby version, it's specified correctly in the application, but then it seems like it's somehow not installed in railway?) when I go to deploy. I don't know much about deployment so I'm trying to understand better how it works and if I can install what I need for my app or if it's a limitation out of my control if I want to use their servers (in which case maybe I can't move away from heroku so easily due to dependencies in their tech stack?).